# Fligner test in R, with several variables indicating the grouping

Tags: r, anova, heteroscedasticity

I have to run an multiple way Anova and want to test the assumption of homoscedasticity.

How can I run a Fligner.test with several independent variables (variables indicating the grouping) with R? Does it make sense to do such a thing?

Comment: Oh and indeed, in the R help I see that I can use a formula. Therefore it works. I thought I could only two input in the function `x`and `g`. Ok, thank you!

Comment: Your other question is worth mentioning here: [Inspecting assumption of homoscedasticity](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76973/32036)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of using the fligner.test() function. You can either do

> fligner.test(x=…, g=…)

or

> fligner.test(formula= a~b+c+d, data=your_data)

The second case allows to check an anova model with several independent variables.

And yes, it totally makes sense to run a Fligner test with several grouping variables.

Comment: Usually one-line answers aren't regarded as appropriate, and in this case, you should probably expand on it to also respond to your second question (presumably in the affirmative).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the use of the formula `fligner.test(formula= a~b+c+d, data=your_data)`.

The `fligner.test` will only take into account the first factor when you use this notation (see example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76887/fligner-test-with-r)).

A more appropriate way to handle multiple independent variables is with the formula `fligner.test(a ~ interaction(a, b, c, d), data=your_data)`. This will make sure that the order you use for your independent variables does not impact your output (i.e., p-value).